# How does Nmap decide which DNS servers to use?

Tags: dns, nmap

I had [a problem using Nmap](https://superuser.com/questions/731419/why-is-nmap-slow-on-my-windows-8-1-laptop) which turned out to be down the list of DNS servers Nmap was using for reverse DNS.  There were 2 correct DNS servers and two strange ones.  The problem was solved/worked around by specifying the DNS servers or by using `--system-dns` which according the man page is usually *slower* than allowing Nmap to do it.

Now I can't find anywhere on my system that the other IP addresses are specified.  Normal `nslookup` uses the right settings and works fine, `ipconfig /all` does not show the strange ones on any interface.

So where does Nmap get them from?

Answer (score 0):

From the nmap man page:

```
--dns-servers server1[,server2[,...]]  (Servers to use for reverse DNS queries) .
    By default, Nmap determines your DNS servers (for rDNS resolution) from your
    resolv.conf file (Unix) or the Registry (Win32). Alternatively, you may use this
    option to specify alternate servers.
```

I'm not a Windows Registry expert, but it would be interesting to find where Windows stores DNS information in the Registry, and look there to see if you can find the "strange" ones there.

Comment: Win Registry: *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{AdapterIdentifier}* --> for each adapter there is the property *"NameServer"* where DNS servers can be specified. I assume that those are the ones the MAN page talks about (at least `ipconfig` is supposed to use them).

Comment: Not sure, but it might be getting closer.  In that Registry location I have 11 interfaces listed, but "NameServer" is blank for all. There is another key "DhcpNameServer" which is populated though.  Nmap is using 4 DNS servers, two of which match the two configured for my current connection.  One of the others that Nmap is using is in the "DhcpNameServer" key for an interface used by a disconnected VPN.  The fourth DNS server is not listed anywhere.