# nmap takes minutes to scan localhost

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, centos, nmap

I'm trying to run `nmap` to see what ports my computer has open, as part of following [this guide to set up docker](http://devops.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/How-To-Guide-1.pdf). I use

```
sudo nmap -sU -sS -T4 --defeat-rst-ratelimit -p 1-65535 localhost
```

This takes forever. I dropped it down to only 500 ports, and it takes about 45 *seconds*. On the guide, I see that scanning all 65000 ports should only take ~3 seconds. I have no idea what is going on.

The system is a fresh Centos 7.4.1708 (installed last night). It's not a great laptop by any means (circa 2010) but it doesn't make sense that it would be this many orders of magnitude slower. I'm behind a consumer router but I don't think that should matter as I'm doing a localhost scan.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated. I tried [the commands suggested in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/731419/why-is-nmap-slow-on-my-windows-8-1-laptop)

```
nmap -d -n -Pn -p 4730 localhost

nmap -d -n -sn localhost

nmap -d -sL localhost
```

and got very fast responses, with the first one taking 0.07s and the rest taking 0.01s. A single port scan is fairly rapid, but it is very slow for a large number of ports. Also, removing `--defeat-rst-ratelimit` and `-T4` did not change the speed noticeably.

The answer to this question is probably embarrassingly obvious, as I know almost nothing about networking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nmap is not the best tool to use for this. I love Nmap, and my full time job is working on and promoting it, but this is one case where it is not the best tool for the job. The Linux kernel keeps exhaustive records of what ports are open and which processes have them open, and common command-line tools can query this. The command which is going to be most useful to you is `netstat -tulnp`, which lists all listening (`-l`) TCP (`-t`) and UDP (`-u`) port numbers (`-n`) and their associated process IDs (`-p`). Some systems are deprecating the netstat command, so you can use [`ss`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) instead: `ss -tunpo state listening`

As to why Nmap is taking so long, the most likely cause is the UDP scan (`-sU`). Nmap wants to find which ports are open and which are closed, but UDP doesn't require a response packet from open ports. Instead, it sends an ICMP Port Unreachable message in response to probes to closed ports. Linux rate-limits these ICMP messages, so Nmap has to slow way down in order to distinguish the "open port, no response" silence from the "closed port, but it's not time to send a ICMP message yet" silence.

Comment: I thought nmap would act more as a confirmation - not only do you not have processes running, but also yes your ports are definitely closed, you did iptables stuff right, good job.

As for UDP scans beings low, that answer makes sense, but then I don't understand how [this guide on page 6](http://devops.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/How-To-Guide-1.pdf) got such a fast response.

Comment: iptables rules will not be tested if you run against localhost, since the packets are not inbound. You can remove the rate limit yourself, if you wish. [The icmp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/icmp) shows that you can set the `icmp_ratelimit` to `0` to disable it: `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit`

Comment: Oh. Those are good things to know. Thanks for your help!